# userid in locally built library

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

If I build a library (for example Quantlib: http://sourceforge.net/projects/quantlib/files/QuantLib/1.2/QuantLib-1.2.tar.gz/download), I see that my userid is encoded in the built library.

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-boost-include=/usr/include/boost --with-boost-lib=/usr/lib && make -j3 && sudo make install

$ grep rajanikanth /usr/local/lib/libQuantLib.*
Binary file /usr/local/lib/libQuantLib.a matches
Binary file /usr/local/lib/libQuantLib.so matches
Binary file /usr/local/lib/libQuantLib.so.0 matches
Binary file /usr/local/lib/libQuantLib.so.0.0.0 matches
```

Is this normal?

Is there anyway to prevent the userid from appearing in the locally built library?

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I see that my userid is encoded in the built library.

This is most likely because

1. you built the library with COPTS=`-O2 -g` (which is the default most `configure` scripts will use when building with `gcc`).
2. you built it in your home directory, which looks like `/home/rajanikanth` or some such

> Is there anyway to prevent the userid from appearing in the locally built library?

You can avoid this by building non-debug version (`make -j3 CFLAGS=-O2`), or by building it in a "generic" directory, e.g. `/tmp/build-quantlib`